# Int cannot be deferenced error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, int, dereference

I am trying to take the user input from one method and use it in another.  I am confused about the error because they are both of type int.

---

```
public static void move()
{
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userMove = scan.nextInt();
}

public static void usersMove(String playerName, int gesture)
{
    int userMove = userMove.move(); //error is here

    if (userMove == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: move() has return type as void, make it int and return the value.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - even then its wrong. You can't call a method on a primitive data type.

Comment: I was assuming that userMove is an object, otherwise you are right. May be he has messed up the names in the post.

Comment: Actually, the OP wants to call the `move()` method to get the value for `userMove`, which is an `int`. Must have got confused on how to call that method, and hence, the error.

Comment: Yes, even move() needs to return that value and change its return type to int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int userMove = userMove.menu();
```

`userMove` here is an `int`(primitive data type). How can you call a method on that?

I'm guessing that you want something like this:-

```
public static int move()
{
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userMove = scan.nextInt();
    return userMove;
}

public static void usersMove(String playerName, int gesture)
{
    int userMove = move(); //Now error will go.

    if (userMove == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I am now getting an incompatible type area. Is this because of my return statement?
  int userMove = menu();
                     ^
  required: int
  found:    void

Comment: Your `menu()` method should also return `int` because its return value assigned to `userMove`.

Comment: see my answer. I've changed the return value of `move()` method. Make that change too.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, since it is not clear what userMove is... but you seem to use a variable from another method in the caller. You need to return it to do that

```
public static int move()
{
   System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   return scan.nextInt();
}

public static void usersMove(String playerName, int gesture)
{
   int userMove = move(); //error is here

   if (userMove == -1)
   {
       break;
   }
```